# Hydration Error when using next-usequerystate with Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hydration

I'm running a very simple example listed on the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-usequerystate) for `next-usequerystate` itself.

Here's the code:

```js
import { useQueryState } from 'next-usequerystate'

export default () => {
  const [name, setName] = useQueryState('name')
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello, {name || 'anonymous visitor'}!</h1>
      <input value={name || ''} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => setName(null)}>Clear</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

I'm not adding or changing any code. On the first load, it works just fine. It's supposed to store the state in the URL itself. The URL changes to reflect the state just fine but when I try to load the website with the state mentioned in the URL. I get this error.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Call Stack
updateHostRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (19849:0)
beginWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (21615:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27426:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26557:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26466:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26434:0)
recoverFromConcurrentError
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25850:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25750:0)
workLoop
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (266:0)
flushWork
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (239:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (533:0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. A fix that worked for me was to ensure that the Next.js router is ready before rendering.

In `_app.tsx`:

```
// src/pages/app.tsx

import { useRouterReady } from "@/hooks/useRouterReady";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const isRouterReady = useRouterReady();
  return (
      {isRouterReady ? <Component {...pageProps} /> : null}
  );
```

Where `useRouterReady` is a custom hook inspired by [this guide](https://dev.to/jeffsalive/solving-the-challenge-of-state-persistence-in-nextjs-effortless-state-management-with-query-parameters-4a6p):

```
// src/hooks/useRouterReady.ts

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export const useRouterReady = () => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsReady(router.isReady);
  }, [router.isReady]);

  return isReady;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of next-usequerystate.

In the pages router, Next.js doesn't have access to the query parameters on the initial server side rendering (when it's a static page it makes sense, but it also didn't have them on server-side rendered pages, until Next.js 13.4).

This causes next-usequerystate to use the default value (or `null` if none provided like the demo here) on SSR. When the code hydrates, it needs to account for that default value being potentially out of sync with the current URL.

@swimmer's answer is the correct way to do this: wait for hydration to complete, with the default value from SSR being used for the hydration render, then re-render with the correct URL value once the page is hydrated (ie: when the Next.js router is ready).

Note that with version 1.8+ of next-usequerystate and Next.js 13.4+, which uses the new Next.js router implementations, this limitation doesn't apply to fully server-side rendered pages anymore (ones that implement `getServerSideProps`).

Comment: Is there really no other workaround for pages routing? I imagine this is terrible for SEO